# Spring remote service integration test. Jetty vs AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, embedded-jetty

I'm doing Spring Remote Service via HTTPInvoker. And I'd like to write integration tests for that, I have two techniques in mind which I'm not sure which one is better or I completely misunderstand the two techniques.

I'm a bit confused with these two techniques. One technique is that Spring has the ability to load the context before the test already, so I could just specify the context xml. The other technique is to have Embedded Jetty to load the context and we have another test to hit the endpoint. I'm not sure which one is better.

I get the idea of Embedded Jetty testing from here. http://code.google.com/p/jianwikis/wiki/SpringHttpRemotingWithEmbeddedJettyServer

The other way is to have that inside the test case. For example,

```
@ContextConfiguration(location = {"/application_context.xml"})
public class SpringIntegrationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

   @Autowired
   private TheService theService
   ...
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing both?

Thanks a lot.